# R Newbie - Histograms/Frequency of values incorporating a quantity Column

Tags: r

Haven't had much success with googling this one.  New R user.  Suspect the answer is with reshape/plyr but haven't been able to figure it out.

I have data in this form: 
sampling interval, recorded value, # times value was recorded

e.g

```
45.3, 17, 3 
48, 19, 2
```

Doing a histogram of the data, I just get a histogram containing 17, 19.  When really my data is 17,17,17,19,19

I can write a loop to go through the times recorded column and create a new data column, but it's awkward and I'm sure I'm over-thinking this.

Is there a simple function to turn this into a data frame that would be:

```
45.3, 17 
45.3, 17 
45.3, 17 
48, 19
48, 19
```

Comment: Close viote explanation: I think the answer that Michael Lawrence provided to a very similar answer was better since it mentioned rep() and barplot().

Comment: Perfect.  You are right.  As far as stackoverflow rules go, once something has been marked as duplicate, is there anything the original author needs to do to agree?  Certainly don't want to clutter up the place.

Comment: There really is no mechanism for proper merging of questions and answers. There can be removal, but that typically is reserved for offensive postings or utterly clueless or or egregious violation of the norms of the site. Even the answer that @agstudy "deleted" is still visible to those of us with a few more rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dat$V3` to indicate how often you need each row of `dat`, by feeding it into the `times` parameter of `rep()`:

```
>  dat <- read.table(text='45.3, 17, 3 
  + 48, 19, 2',sep=',')
> dat[rep(1:nrow(dat),times=dat$V3),]
      V1 V2 V3
1   45.3 17  3
1.1 45.3 17  3
1.2 45.3 17  3
2   48.0 19  2
2.1 48.0 19  2
```

Comment: +1! I will delete my stupid answer :)

Comment: Perfect.  I knew this would be something simple.  This is what I get from being a non-programmer teaching myself just enough to get myself in trouble.